# Adjust day height in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a calendar that was customized and working with FullCalendar version 1. Now, I've updated it to version 3. I've updated the CSS and settings to match what I had before, but cannot find a way to adjust the day height in the month view.

On the left is the old display and on the right is the new display, where the day cells are too tall.

[image]

I would do it in CSS, but the height of the week is dynamically set by the code so should be adjustable.

The old version resulted in this:

[image]

and the new version results in this:

[image]

How do I tell the code what I want?

Comment: The routine that does this appears to be `distributeHeight` but I haven't (yet) determined how to make it do this.

Answer (score 8):

Solved. Turned out to require two settings.

In the CCS, make the `min-height` smaller:

```
.fc-body .fc-row { min-height: 45px; }
```

And in code, change the aspectRatio to a new 'magic' number:

```
.fullCalendar({
   aspectRatio: 1.09
});
```

Changing the `aspectRatio` without first reducing the `min-height` does not result in a height less than the `min-height`.